# How many times the finalizer method is called and zombies (PEP 442)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4

I arose a doubt about the finalizer method `__del__`.
The `__del__` method is called just before the object is cleaned up, but this method can even resurrect the object. Now I have noticed that in Python 2.7 the finalizer is called *everytime* the object's reference counter drops zero (even if the object was already resurrected), insted in Python3.4 it is called just *once* for all the entire life of the object, so if it is resurrected and then it counter drops to zero the finalizer method is not called anymore.

From the [PEP 442](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/) I read that in python 3.4 this choise was due to prevent resurrecting zombies:

> However, if the object was already finalized, then the finalizer isn't called. This prevents us from finalizing zombies

My doubt is that I can't figure out how this solution can prevent us from finalizing zombies, can you make me some concrete examples? In addition the object can be resurrected only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have the following class:

```
class RefCycle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.refcycle = self
    def __del__(self):
        print('finalizing')
        print(self.refcycle)
```

and we create and collect a cyclic isolate:

```
RefCycle()
import gc
gc.collect()
```

When the garbage collector detects the cyclic isolate, it calls the `RefCycle` instance's finalizer. Then, it starts to break references. When it clears the `self.refcycle` attribute, the object's refcount drops to 0.

This is where it's important that finalized objects are not refinalized. If that "already finalized" flag weren't there, the object would be refinalized as a consequence of the refcount going to 0. Since the garbage collector has already messed with the object's attributes, this would be a very bad thing. The "already finalized" flag protects us from this scenario.

Comment: I tried your code, but I get nothing no `'finalizing'` printed, even once.

Comment: @antox: We haven't created nearly enough garbage for the cyclic GC to trigger. You could run `gc.collect()` to force a collection.

Comment: sorry for the late, a question, introducing this "already finalized" flag it leads to resurrect objects only just 1 time in their entire life, I mean if previosuly they were resurrected by their `__del__` method, once, let's suppose, their counter drops to zero they can't resurrect again, isn't it?

Comment: @antox: Objects can only be resurrected by their own finalizer once. They can still be resurrected by the finalizers of other objects in a cyclic isolate, but they will never be refinalized.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a reason but help me if it's not the correct one.

Following the PEP 442 the disposal of CI traditionally works this way:

1. Weakrefs to CI objects are cleared, and their callbacks called. At
   this point, the objects are still safe to use.
2. The CI becomes a CT as the GC systematically breaks all known references inside it (using the tp_clear function).
3. Nothing. All CT objects should have been disposed of in step 2 (as a side-effect of clearing references); this collection is finished.

With the new proposal it becomes:

1. Weakrefs to CI objects are cleared, and their callbacks called. At this point, the objects are still safe to use.
2. **The finalizers of all CI objects are called.**
3. **The CI is traversed again to determine if it is still isolated. If it is determined that at least one object in CI is now reachable from outside the CI, this collection is aborted and the whole CI is resurrected. Otherwise, proceed.**
4. The CI becomes a CT as the GC systematically breaks all known references inside it (using the tp_clear function).
5. Nothing. All CT objects should have been disposed of in step 4 (as a side-effect of clearing references); this collection is finished.

So as you can see the step 2 of the former and the step 4 of the latter are identical, in particular they use the same function `tp_clear`, now (and here help me because I didn't read the code and I am not so good to read C code) this function, from what I deduced before destroying an object calls its finalizer, but because it was already called and the CI could have begun a CT and resurrecting a zombie would be an error, the finalizer is called just once.